# How to place icons where I want them?

Tags: html, icons, image

In my current HTML code for icons in my webpage's header, I use the code:

```
<a href=''><img src=''/></a> | <a href=''><img src''/></a>
```

which puts my icons extremly close, next to eachother, but with a "|" between them.

Could someone recommend any preferably HTML code examples, that would allow me to place the icons more specifically and without the "|" in between them.

(Excuse the former poor explanation of my problem!)

Comment: more details would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS inline with HTML which would look like this:

```
<a href='' style='margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px'><img src=''/></a> <a href='' style='margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px'><img src''/></a>
```

This adds a 10px margin to the left and right of each link.

However, adding the CSS in the head of your HTML page would be a better idea:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menuItem {
margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
</style>
```

And then using this as the HTML instead:

```
<a href='' class='menuItem'><img src=''/></a> <a href='' class='menuItem'><img src''/></a>
```